# How to fix android architecture components paging onItemAtEndLoaded get in loop?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, android-paging

I am trying to practice the android architecture components **Paging**

Local + Remote Datasource with Room, MVVM and LiveData

When i first time scroll the list(get **remote** data), it get into loop by **onItemAtEndLoaded** in PagedList.BoundaryCallback, but it scroll smooth when open the activity next time (get **local** data)

Here is my github link [here](https://github.com/huang840801/MVVM-Practice)!

Can anyone take a look and help me how to fix it, Thanks!

Activity

```
class PagingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var viewModel: PagingViewModel
    lateinit var adapter: PagingAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_paging)

        val factory = PagingViewModelFactory(PagingRepository(), application)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,factory).get(PagingViewModel::class.java)
        adapter = PagingAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        viewModel.pagedListLiveData.observe(this, Observer {

            adapter.submitList(it)

        })
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class PagingViewModel(repository: PagingRepository, application: Application) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val pagedListLiveData = repository.getDataItem(application)
}
```

Repository

```
class PagingRepository : PagingRepositoryCallback {

    private lateinit var localDataSource: DataSource.Factory<Int, DataItem>

    override fun getDataItem(application: Application): LiveData<PagedList<DataItem>> {

        val pagedListLiveData: LiveData<PagedList<DataItem>> by lazy {

            localDataSource = DataItemDbHelper(application).getRoomDataItemDao().getAllDataItem()

            val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setPageSize(25)
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .build()

            LivePagedListBuilder(localDataSource, config)
                .setBoundaryCallback(PagingBoundaryCallback(application))
                .build()
        }

        return pagedListLiveData
    }
}

interface PagingRepositoryCallback {
    fun getDataItem(application: Application): LiveData<PagedList<DataItem>>
}
```

BoundaryCallback

```
class PagingBoundaryCallback(context: Context) :
    PagedList.BoundaryCallback<DataItem>() {

    private var page = 2

    private val api = AllPlayerApi.api

    private val dao = DataItemDbHelper(context).getRoomDataItemDao()

    override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
        super.onZeroItemsLoaded()

        api.getAllPlayer().enqueue(createWebserviceCallback())
    }

    override fun onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd: DataItem) {
        super.onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd)
        api.getAllPlayer(page).clone().enqueue(createWebserviceCallback())
    }

    private fun createWebserviceCallback(): Callback<AllPlayerData> {

        return object : Callback<AllPlayerData> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<AllPlayerData>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.d("Huang", " get player fail ")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<AllPlayerData>?, response: Response<AllPlayerData>) {

                Log.d("Huang", " onResponse " + page)

                response.body()!!.data!!.forEach {
                    it.imageUrl = "https://pdc.princeton.edu/sites/pdc/files/events/new-nba-logo-1.png"
                }

                insertItemsIntoDb(response)
                page++
            }
        }
    }

    private fun insertItemsIntoDb(response: Response<AllPlayerData>) {

        GlobalScope.launch {

            response.body()!!.data!!.forEach {

                dao.insert(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. couldn't find a solution. Please share if you already done

Answer (score 0):

Logic for, If `onItemAtEndLoaded` get the same `itemAtEnd` , then do nothing.

```
var lastItemAtEnd:DataItem? = null
override fun onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd: DataItem) {
    lastItemAtEnd?.timestamp?.apply{
        if(itemAtEnd.timestamp==this){
            return;
        }
    }
    super.onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd)
    api.getAllPlayer(page).clone().enqueue(createWebserviceCallback())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your page size is 25 so Pagelist config should have **setInitialLoadSizeHint** as 25 for avoiding looping/unnecessary call of **onItemAtEndLoaded** method

```
val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setPageSize(25)
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(25) //same as your page size
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been long  but i just post the solution in case someone need.
you should register an observer for your adapter and listen for `onItemRangeInserted` event and if the start position of item range is zero just simply scroll adapter to zero position, this make your `RecyclerView` on first load stay in zero position and by the way you should set `setPrefetchDistance` value smaller than the `setInitialLoadSizeHint`.
This is the Java code for adapters observer

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            if(positionStart == 0)
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
        }
    });
```